# Why are some parts of a udev rule triggered script not working? (use xinput to set mouse acceleration when plugged in)

Tags: usb, udev, xinput

I have a udev rule

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c084", RUN+="/some/script.sh"
```

which successfully triggers a script like

```
#!/bin/bash

ls /tmp >> /tmp/lsasd # this line works
touch /tmp/asdasd # this line works

for id in $(xinput --list | \
            sed -n '/Logitech G203 Prodigy Gaming Mouse.*pointer/s/.*=\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p')
do
  echo $id >> /tmp/test.log 2>&1
  xinput --set-prop $id 'libinput Accel Profile Enabled' 0, 1
  
done
```

The first two commands work fine but setting the property does not work.
The idea is to run the command

```
xinput --set-prop $id 'libinput Accel Profile Enabled' 0, 1
```

for all devices found, because I don't know the `$id` at that point.

Any idea what could be the problem? Are `xinput` devices not available at that point yet?
I tried to add a `sleep 5` to test this but this also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

> The xinput settings only work in an X context. But they are not run
> e.g. from a terminal started in your desktop manager.

e.g.

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c084", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0.0", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/administrator/.Xauthority", RUN+="/some/script.sh"
```

You can read more about it in:

- [Control USB mouse acceleration separately from touchpad speed](http://granjow.net/udev-rules.html)
- [udev rules not executing script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/583513/udev-rules-not-executing-script)
- [udev rule script “xinput --list” differs in terminal versus log](https://superuser.com/questions/924087/udev-rule-script-xinput-list-differs-in-terminal-versus-log)